# Using blade @can directives inside vuejs component

Tags: vue.js, laravel-blade

I am having a blocker right now with regards to using blade `@can` directives inside a vuejs component.

```
@can('view user', $lead)
   <button>view</button>
@endcan
```

Vue displays this as a text instead of using laravel's gate

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a boomer, but you could try adding the `v-cloak` property to your `<button>` tag, and changing the native `@can` directive to an `@if (auth()->user()->can('view_user', $lead))`

This workaround should do the job.